# Possible in Sonar to only view analysis done on new code?

Tags: sonarqube

We have a legacy system that we have taken into our project and building upon. I would be interested in not only analyse the whole project in Sonar, but also to only analyse code added after a specific date. So is it possible in sonar to retrieve a static analysis "view" (coverage, violations, lines of code, etc.) only on code that has been added after a specific date? This would be very helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the specific date in period configuration of project, [this post can help you](http://www.sonarsource.org/differential-services-in-sonar-for-a-complete-support-of-continuous-inspection/).
Period for sonar is "**Period used to compare measures and track new violations**".

Comment: Hmm so if I understand that post correctly: 1) It is not possible to dynamically set a rule that "show me code violations on SCM activity after 01.01.2012", but 2) It is possible to dynamically set a rule that "show me code coverage on new code committed after 01.01.2012"? So for violations it is not possible, but for code coverage it is?

Comment: Both "Period" definition and "Cutoff Plugin" filter violations and coverage. Both are metrics for Sonar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cut off plugin ( http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Cutoff+Plugin ) that allows you to exclude files from analysis based on a cutoff date threshold (or a cutoff period). Any source file that was last modified prior to the configured cutoff date is excluded.

Comment: Does this mean that I need to have two separate Ant targets, one that analyses the whole project and another one using the Cutoff plugin that analyses only code committed after a specific date? It would be nice if the Cutoff plugin could be used as the TimeMachine, dynamic.

Comment: If you want to analyse the whole project AND new code after a specific date then you need two different analysis ( using sonar.branch property ) If you need only analysis on new code then do the following
1. Run a complete analysis of your project
2. Install and configure cut-off plugin
3. Run a new analysis - This will be based on the cut-off plugin

and voila! :)

Comment: yes, I need to 1) analyse whole project from the beginning of time, once a day and 2) only new code after every check-in. Thanks.

Comment: ... giving a second though, do I actually need to re-analyse the whole project every night? Given the example you provided, if I 1) analyse full project and then 2) define cutoff-plugin for e.g. 2 days, does it show the results of the full analysis too after that? Does TimeMachine still work? Any risks here? :)