# Jenkins and Sonar, possible to analyse only committed code using Ant?

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, sonarqube

I am using Java+Ant+Jenkins+Sonar. Sonar analyses our code during every night. Is it possible to have Sonar analyse only new committed code in Jenkins, not the whole project? Again, we are using Ant not Maven. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer have already a response. See [Possible in Sonar to only view analysis done on new code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256968/possible-in-sonar-to-only-view-analysis-done-on-new-code)

The solution is based on the Cutoff Plugin for sonar.

Comment: but to my understanding the is a very "static" way to do it. I.e. once you have set the cutoff time, you can't dynamically change it e.g. per build?

Comment: Ok, my next question would be how to define the project name and version from Jenkins down to Ant script, but I will open a new quesitno for this :)